# Is there a version of multivariate multinomial logit?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution

I'm working with a data set with 2-3 response variables and 7 predictor variables. All the variables are categorical. If there were just one response variable, I think a multinomial logit would be the right model, but there are 2 or 3. So my question is - is there a multivariate version of the multinomial logit?

I've looked at several books on categorical data, but haven't seen anything like this (mainly using Agresti 2002).

I have about 2000 observations, though I'll probably need to split it up into 2 or 3 data subsets to really see what's going on. One thing I was thinking about is converting it to counts and use a model for count data. I could also combine the 2-3 response vars into 1 categorical with a lot of categories, but I think that will lower the chances of anything showing up for any of the categories. I could also do 2-3 separate models, one for each variable, which is obviously not as good.

I might also be able to get rid of some of the predictors (I think 3 of the 7 have the most explanatory power). I'm not opposed to using machine learning methods, I've found some interesting stuff already with decision trees.

thanks,

-paul

Comment: in multivariate regression if you estimate each equation separately you lose out only in efficiency, the estimates of the coefficients and their standard errors are estimated correctly. I suspect that the same should hold for multivariate multinomial logit.

Comment: Mpiktas' hunch is right. There exists multivariate multinomial logit models and I have seen it in Agresti 2002. I will get back with the exact page numbers as I dont have the book on me. But I have seen the theory being developed in the same chapter in which they introduce Mutivariate logit; I think immediately after the horse-shoe crabs or crocodile examples.

Comment: May not be what you're looking for, but it might be worth considering mixed effects multinomial logit models. Yet another approach would be to look at package `drm` in R, which claims to do regression for clustered variables using "dependence ratios" to  model intra-unit association (http://www.helsinki.fi/~jtjokine/drm/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agresti 2007 discusses them.  They're in chapter 9 and 10. The 2002 edition probably discusses them too, as @suncoolsu mentioned.

Agresti refers to the group of response variables as a *cluster* and discusses according analysis with marginal models, conditional models and generalized estimating equations.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It was the terminology that got me - I didn't realize clustered/repeated response data meant basically the same thing as mutlivariate in regression, but it seems that's the case.

In Agresti 2002 I think it's Ch. 11 & 12. 2007 and 2002 cover most of the same stuff, but '02 is a little more in depth. 

Time to read those chapters.